# Autoload для Composer

Tags: php, composer, autoload

Пишу свою первую библиотеку с `composer.json`.

Сейчас json выглядит так:

```
{
    "name": "...",
    ...
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0" : {
            "Ground\\" : "src/Ground"
        }
    },
    "require": {}
}
```

Файлы расположены так:

```
src/
    Ground/
        Abstraction/
            IGrid.php (интерфейс в namespace Ground\Abstraction)
        Base/
            Grid.php (класс в namespace Ground\Base)
```

Импортировал библиотеку в *Symfony2* (успешно всё загрузилось в *vendor*), в контроллере прописал:

```
use Ground\Base\Grid;
```

В *экшене* этого контроллера:

```
new Grid(50, 50);
```

Эта строка выдает 2 ошибки:

> Fatal error: Class 'Ground\Base\Grid' not found in ...(указывает на строку в экшене)

И самая интересная:

> Fatal error: Interface 'Ground\Base\Abstraction\IGrid' not found in /.../symfony/vendor/.../ground/src/Ground/Base/Grid.php on line 8 (указывает на объявление класса Grid, там где implements IGrid)

т.е. в файл с классом `Grid` всё-таки попали. Но выдало ошибку (первую).

Как правильно прописать *автолоад* в моем случае?

Comment: 1) namespace какой? 2) пробовали `use \Ground\Base\Grid;`?

Comment: 1) `namespace` соответствует папкам начиная с `Ground`, т.е. `Grid` лежит в `src/Ground/Base`, следовательно полное имя класса `Ground\Base\Grid`. 2) Попробовал (если Вы про слэш в начале) - ничего не поменялось

Comment: Поставьте psr-4, как минимум. И не тестируйте прямо на симфони, лучше отдельно от нее.

Comment: у меня когда проблемы с импортом возникают - я в автолоад лезу и там дебажу. У вас смущает строчка в composer.json: `"Ground\\" : "src/Ground"` попробуйте убрать `/Ground`, т.е. оставить `"Ground\\" : "src"` (два обратных слеша я бы тоже убрал, но их вроде пишут)

Comment: ВОРОН, это правильный ответ. Я правда сам докумекал, уже коммит успел сделать. Залез в файл `autoload_namespaces`, там нашел свой пакет, и понял в чем дело. Делайте коммент ответом, я отмечу как правильный. (по поводу убрать `/Ground`).

Comment: Правильно вам @Etki сказал - надо psr-4 использовать, тогда у вас все бы правильно подключалось, т.к. namespase в нем не требует наличия в папках. Сейчас в ответе напишу

Comment: да psr-0 должен быть совместим с psr-4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Читаем [документацию](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4) composer'а по автозагрузке (перевод):

> > Под ключом `psr-4` (в composer.json) вы определяете отображение неймспейсов на пути, расположенные относительно корневого каталога пакета. Когда загружается класс `Foo\\Bar\\Baz`, префикс неймспейса `Foo\\` указывает на каталог `src/`, что означает что автозагрузчик должен искать файл `src/Bar/Baz.php` и подключать его, если такой файл существует. Обратите внимание, что в отличие от PSR-0, префикс (`Foo\\`) не включается в путь файла

Т.е. если у вас имеется следующая структура каталогов (относительно корневой директории пакета):

```
src/
    Ground/
        Abstraction/
            IGrid.php
        Base/
            Grid.php
```

то для PSR-4 вы должны использовать следующее определение в composer.json (пути поиска указывают на каталоги классов без имени неймспейса):

```
{
    ...
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4" : {
            "Ground\\" : "src/Ground"
        }
    }
}
```

А в PSR-0 пути поиска должны указывать на родительский каталог неймспейса (чтобы каталог с именем неймспейса был в путях поиска):

```
{
    ...
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0" : {
            "Ground\\" : "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

---

Отличие PSR-4 от PSR-0 проще увидеть на следующем примере:

Допустим мы изменили название папки `Ground` на `GroundNew`.

Т.е. теперь у нас следующая структура папок:

```
src/
    GroundNew/
        Abstraction/
            IGrid.php
        Base/
            Grid.php
```

Стандарт PSR-0 требует изменить неймспейсы всех наших классов (с `Ground\Base\Grid` на `GroundNew\Base\Grid;`) и изменить описание маппинга классов в composer.json:

```
"GroundNew\\" : "src/"
```

Для стандарта PSR-4 достаточно было бы изменить только путь неймспейса:

```
"Ground\\" : "src/GroundNew"
```

оставив название неймспейса прежним (т.е. `Ground\Base\Grid`)

Comment: спасибо за разъяснения.