# Неправильно работает extends в PHP 7?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, ооп, php7

Недавно перешел на PHP7, в целом миграция прошла хорошо, за исключением того, что PHP не хочет видеть класс-родитель у потомков (ООП).

Есть директория, в которой находится список файлов-классов, некоторые классы базовые, некоторые наследуются через extends (например, class User_Activation extends User). Сборка осуществляется автоматически:

```
$includes_dir = opendir('./includes/core');
  while (($inc_file = readdir($includes_dir)) != false)
    if (strstr($inc_file,'.php')) include('./includes/core/'.$inc_file);
```

В директории файлы лежат в виде:

```
class_user.php
class_user_activation.php
...
class_user_gallery.php
...
```

Когда запускается скрипт, то выкидывает ошибку, что класс User не найден (не найден объект наследования), хотя он даже по порядку файла должен был уже загрузиться. В PHP 5 все работает как надо.

Если прописать вручную загрузку первым файла class_user.php, то все работает как надо.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Видимо, файлы читаются из директории не в том порядке, в которым вы ожидаете. Добавьте отладку перед include и станет ясно. А вообще странно - на пхп-7 вы перешли, а на автолоадер - нет. PSR4 уже успел выйти на замену предшественнику PSR0, а вы всё руками инклудите. низачот!

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453699/176064

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string readdir ([ resource $dir_handle ] )
```

> Возвращает имя следующего по порядку элемента каталога. Элементы возвращаются в том порядке, в котором они хранятся в файловой системе.

Вы уверены, что в вашей ФС файлы хранятся именно в том порядке, как вам надо? Я бы на это не закладывался. Никогда.

И как правильно отметил @Lexx918, давно пора перейти на [автозагрузку классов](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.spl-autoload-register.php)